# Polymorphic Relationship with Multiple Associations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to use an intermediary table to signify a sponsorship relationship between two different user tables (Employee & Non-Employee) with the following requirements:

- A sponsor can be *either* an Employee or Non-Employee.
- An Employee/Non-Employee can belong to only one sponsor.
- An Employee can have many sponsors.

I noticed that Polymorphic Relationships for Laravel only support single associations.  Typically they use the intermediary table in the relationship to prevent having to create multiple tables with the same signature.  In my case, I need to polymorph both sides of the relationship since at any point I could have the sponsor/sponsored person belong to either table.  I'm not sure if I'm going about this right, sort of stumped at the moment.

Here's what I currently have:

```
Employees
id
sponsor_id

NonEmployees
id
sponsor_id

Sponsors
id
sponsorable_id
sponsorable_type
```

Next, I setup the following models:

Models/Employee.php

```
public function sponsors() {
    return $this->morphMany('Sponsor', 'sponsorable');
}
```

Models/NonEmployee.php

```
public function sponsors() {
    return $this->morphMany('Sponsor', 'sponsorable');
}
```

Models/Sponsor.php

```
public function sponsorable() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

With this setup, I was able to perform general lookup queries against the Sponsors table and then reverse engineer them to retrieve the name of the sponsor.

```
Sponsor::with('sponsorable')->get();
Sponsor::find(1)->sponsorable;
```

Comment: What you describe for the the relationship between 'sponsor' and 'employees' looks like a 'tree' structure. Is that correct? i.e. one employee could be both a 'sponsor' and also being 'sponsored' by another employee?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The same goes for the 'non-employees'.  For this specific question, there's little difference between them except that they're in different tables with different schemas.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have logic in place to enforce your rules? I am thinking in terms of 'cycles' in the 'relationships. More as 'directed graphs'. What would happen in the processing if 'cycles' happen?

Comment: The sponsorship functionality is something new I'm working on, so it's not set in stone if there's a better way to go about this other than the fact that the requirements are set by the client.  I'm not sure I follow your line of thinking with cycling and directed graphs.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: e.g. Employee A sponsors Employee B who sponsors Employee C who sponsors empolyee A. etc. Just guessing here. It may not be an issue.

Comment: More guessing... You could simplify the issue by ensuring that 1) Employees can either sponsor another employee _or_ be sponsored by another employee but not both? External sponsors can do what they want with their money, It is always welcome. You may be able to map this to your database more easily.

Comment: Some interesting questions posed there, not positive about their impact yet but I feel equipped to handle those should they be issues. Regarding my original question, however, any thoughts on how to make these polymorphic relationships with multiple associations work in Laravel?

Comment: Enjoy the programming. It sounds like fun and will be interesting :) Alas, i have nothing useful to add as regards the 'polymorphic relationships with multiple associations' in Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with the following idea to utilize the existing Polymorphic Relationship to handle multiple associations.

First, I changed the schema to this:

```
Employees
id

NonEmployees
id

Sponsors
id
sponsored_id
sponsored_type
sponsorable_id
sponsorable_type
```

So, I removed the sponsor_id field from each of the account type tables and added a second polymorphic relationship to the Sponsors table.

I updated the models as follows:

Models/Employee.php & Models/NonEmployee.php

```
public function sponsorable()
{
    return $this->morphOne('Sponsor', 'sponsorable');
}

public function sponsors()
{
    return $this->morphMany('Sponsor', 'sponsor');
}
```

Models/Sponsor.php

```
public function sponsor()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function sponsorable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Now, because Laravel doesn't support a morphManyThrough() relationship type, you'll notice I changed some of the names of the functions so that it would read a little cleaner when using the relationships since I have to go from one table through an intermediary table and then to a 3rd table to get the information I want.

With this structure, I can do the following:

```
$employee = Employee::find(2)->sponsorable->sponsor; // Gets employee's sponsored party
$sponsors = $employee->sponsors; // Gets individual that the employee is sponsoring.
foreach ($sponsors as $sponsor)
    echo $sponsor->sponsorable->first_name;
$employee->sponsors()->save(new Sponsor()); // New sponsor
$non_employee->sponsors()->save(new Sponsor()); // New sponsor
```

I can also perform a reverse lookup:

```
Sponsor::find(1)->sponsor->first_name; // Sponsoring party
Sponsor::find(1)->sponsorable->first_name; // Party being sponsored
```

Comment: The above code is still in use for the application I needed it for.  Honestly, the trickiest part was the grammar for a Sponsor because the Sponsoring party is a "sponsor" and the party being sponsored is also a "sponsor".  That was more of a naming convention hurdle than a code one.